# SQL Trigger vs Other Options Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I've got a table in SQL holding Alarm data from an iFix SCADA system that is designed as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FIXALARMS](
    [ALM_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ALM_NATIVETIMEIN] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ALM_PHYSLNODE] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [ALM_TAGNAME] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [ALM_VALUE] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [ALM_MSGTYPE] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [ALM_DESCR] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ALM_ALMSTATUS] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [ALM_ALMPRIORITY] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [ALM_ALMAREA] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
)
```

The SCADA designates what the columns must be named and the datatypes and gives no other options to split the data into multiple tables.  Pretty much, I'll be forced to take in information in this format and it's become a pain because a lot of my queries are using multiple like's and string comparisons on data that really should be id'd.

Now, I would like to normalize this table and split it into multiple tables with keyed relationships so that I can save database space, query performance, and add a bit of flexibility.

Would this be best achieved by using database triggers?  The database is growing at about 40Mb/Day (~300k rows) and my lack of SQL experience makes me fear adding extra load to the server when an entry is being added.  Instead should I use an agent to just clean the table up every now and then?  What would be some other options that I might not know about?

Comment: Before I look at the question, which SCADA system is this ? Which industry...if you don't mind.

Comment: iFix for a Diary Plant

Comment: The fact that your database is growing at that rate doesn't speak much about how quickly this particular table (or tables that you have in mind when you speak about normalizing it) would grow. When you're considering the performance impact of a trigger, it mainly has to do with the table(s) in question.

Comment: One option would be to make `FIXALARMS` a view and use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view to slice-and-dice the data into the appropriate tables. (I'll also point out that this way lies madness, but it says you can do it right here on page 666,666 of this new book I got, called "Necronomicon For Dummies"...).

Comment: So you're saying that database growth would be a bad performance measure right?

Comment: I'm doing all of my filtering in views right now but doesn't that still query the database every time it's executed?  Or is that cached after one query and updated with new information?

Comment: Database growth is not so relevant. when you consider a trigger, you consider how much the added CPU/IO cycles will impact your throughput on that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the data realtime, use SSIS to set up an ETl process to transform the data to your normalized form.

If you must have the data realtime, then use triggers but use them very carefully and make sure they handle sets of data. Sql server triggers should never be expected to handle only one row of data. You would want to make sure your trigger code is as performant as it can be since you have high data entry onteh table you are grabbing the data from. That means you need to read a good book on performance tuning techniques, so you know what query forms to avoid using such as correlated subqueries, non-sargable where clauses, cursors. You would want to expensively test under load for blocking issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are going to add some processing overhead and possibly introduce contention and transactional locks. If the complicated queries are not being executed against data that is complete up-to-the-minute, then you could get by with a regularly scheduled ETL process that extracts the data and translates if to a more usable form.
You could schedule the ETL to run daily or every few hours as required.

Comment: Change data capture ?

Comment: If I am trying to run queries against complete up-to-the-minute information would it be a good practice to use an ETL process to move the information, then run the complicated queries on that information in a view unioned with the latest raw data?

Comment: If you're going to ETL the RAW data then hopefully you will not need to join back to it. The RAW data sounds like it is unstructured and an ETL process can copy out what is required into a structure that is more usable for queries (3NF or a star-schema ). You might keep a reference back to the RAW data for audit purposes, but your copies of the data in 3NF or a star-schema should be used for queries that perform well and are easier to maintain. The method you use for populating your new clean structures will depend on output requirements, realtime triggers or scheduled batches.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you go with a trigger, most likely it will be breaking incoming data into multiple tables, right? 
This is a viable approach. 
If the incoming data matches the schema of that table, you do a "regular" trigger. consider INSTEAD OF triggers, if incoming data schema doesn't perfectly match your schema.

In any case, in your trigger you will have to generated keys during some INSERTs and re-use them in others. Some good practices are to keep your trigger business-logic free - only do RDBMS things in it. Also carefully consider how you generate and read back keys - beware of scope contamination. Lastly, consider your transaction isolation levels and keep things as quick as possible to keep your throughput in check.